# ASPX Client side SQL connection string

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am building a web page, and I want to bind a gridview with a client side SQL server database table. (The database is hosted in each user PC and not in the server).

How can I build this SQL connection string?

Comment: File access if very limited from within the browser, access to external resources such as a SQL database is not possible without some plugin. You could, however, use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: ASPX = Active Server Pages. You need a web server running (even if it is a baby one on the client) to use it. If you don't want to use ASP or PHP then you have to use Javascript (runs client side only) and unfortunately it is only good for changing the DOM and using web services. It can't connect directly to a database.

Comment: why to use aspx then? use winforms and for data use excel or access

Comment: build the connection string for one user, take the db path and make sure when you host it on all the PCs path should remain constant

Comment: Why do you have a SQL Server deployed on each client? Anyways, there's nothing preventing the server from accessing the databases running on the clients (call them database servers) except normal networking issues (NAT) and permissions issues, just like connecting to any other database server.

Comment: Same connection string on every host pc and database engine on every client pc I think, but you should use server for this